# Is it possible to cache `lm()` matrices to fit new data?

Tags: r, lm

I wrote an algorithm which fits a linear model with `lm()` and then "updates" the response variable iteratively. The problem is: In a high-dimension scenario, fitting linear models creates a bottleneck.

On the other hand, most of the work required is a matrix inversion that only depends on the covariate matrix `X`, i.e., the coefficients are given by: `solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% X %*% y`.

Reading `lm()` code, I understand that R uses QR decomposition.

Is it possible to recover the internal matrix operation used and fit a new model with new `y` values faster?

Here's a minimal example:

```
set.seed(1)
X <- matrix(runif(400*150000), nrow = 150000)
y1 <- runif(150000)
y2 <- runif(150000)

mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ X)
mod2 <- lm(y2 ~ X)
```

Theoretically, `mod2` "repeats" costful matrix operations identical to the ones made in the first `lm()` call.

I want to keep using `lm()` for its efficient implementation and ability to handle incomplete rank matrices automatically.

Comment: I use the predicted values `mod1$fitted.values`

Comment: Least squares estimation involves a matrix inversion (`solve(t(X) %*% X)`). In high dimension this takes long time, e.g., inverting a 400x400 matrix. This inversion happens (in some more efficient way) each time `lm()` is called, but since `X` is the same in both calls in the example, the second inversion could be skipped if the inversion was cached somehow.

Comment: Reducing the dimensions of `X` (and `y` values accordingly) would create a smaller example data, but that doesn't help illustrate why I want to avoid the repetition as it would run really fast.

Comment: Have a look at `?lm.fit` which offers bare-bones access to the underlying QR code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# Data
set.seed(1)
n = 5
X <- matrix(runif(5*n), nrow = n)
y1 <- runif(n)
y2 <- runif(n)

# lm models
mod1 <- lm(y1 ~ X)
mod2 <- lm(y2 ~ X)

# Obtain QR decomposition of X
q = qr(X)

# Reuse 'q' to obtain fitted values repeatedly
mod1_fv = qr.fitted(q, y1)
mod2_fv = qr.fitted(q, y2)

# Compare fitted values from reusing 'q' to fitted values in 'lm' models
Vectorize(all.equal)(unname(mod1$fitted.values), mod1_fv)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

Vectorize(all.equal)(unname(mod2$fitted.values), mod2_fv)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for! I tried some benchmarks to test whether the "hard work" was on `qr` or `qr.fitted` and indeed this approach "caches" the required values by the use of this `q` variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just fitting a multivariate model? I haven't checked the code, but on my system it's almost half as fast as fitting separately, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's doing what you suggest behind the scenes. That is,

```
mods <- lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ X)
```

Comment: This is correct if you have prior knowledge of `y1` and `y2`, but as I mentioned in the first paragraph, it is used in an iterative process and each subsequent value for `y` depends on the previous iteration, therefore, it doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I was using your minimal example, which didn't include that.